# Change existing module of a project into a mono repo with it's branches and commit history in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules, monorepo

I have a Git repository named A with three branches. It's a multimodule project consisting of modules B, C, D, E, and F, where E and F are submodules in a monorepo. These modules share the same branches as the main repo A. I want to transform module C into a monorepo while retaining the same branches and commit history.

Currently, I am using the following command  to check out the project. This results in a monorepo with submodules E and F. After transforming module C into a monorepo, the clone command should give submodule C. How can I achieve this?

```bash
git clone --recursive https://gitlab..../A.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution to this

```
git clone https://git..../A.git
cd A
for i in $(git branch -r | sed "s/.*origin\///"); do git branch -t $i origin/$i; done
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter C -- --all
git filter-branch --prune-empty --tree-filter 'rm -rf C' -- --all
git remote -v
git remote set-url origin https://git.../C.git
git remote -v
git push -u origin --all
```

//do the following for all branches

```
git clone https://git..../A.git
cd A
```

delete folder c and add submodule ref

```
gi add .
git commit -m "folder removed"
git push origin trunk 
git submodule add https://git..../C.git
cd C
git checkout trunk
git add .
git commit -m "new submodule ref added"
git push origin trunk
```